# Making a text font to scale with UIButton (UIView)

Tags: ios, uitextview, font-size

My form has several buttons with custom background. I managed to make them scaled according to screen size using IB only. However the font size remains same. Is it possible to scale font size using IB (no coding) ?

If it is impossible, there might be a way to get all children of a particular view in the code, so I can write a standard (recursive) function to scale fonts, without listing all text views explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

So you mentioned UIButtons and UITextViews. Assuming you mean resizing the buttons' titleLabels, this is how I would do it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (id subview in self.view.subviews) {

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
            button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
            button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
        }

    }
}
```

Here's a shot in Swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    for subview in self.view.subviews {
        if let button = subview as? UIButton {
            button.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 1;
            button.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
            button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .ByClipping;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You no longer need to specify the `numberOfLines` in iOS 6+. Also you should new set the `minimumScaleFactor`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Dare, but unfortunately this didn't work

I couldn't find anything better that setting the font size manually.
Since all my buttons have same font size, I do:

```
// This constant is found empirically
let rootView = self.view;
let fontSize = CGFloat(rootView.frame.size.width) / 32;

for subview in rootView.subviews {
   if let button = subview as? UIButton {
      let btnLabel = button.titleLabel!
      btnLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
      btnLabel.font = btnLabel.font.fontWithSize(fontSize)
   }
}
```

Actually I would prefer your method ... if it worked.